# Caching with Pagination on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

I have an endpoint which fetches data from the database returns huge number of records. All of this records needs to be visible on the UI but as we scroll the view.

These records are used in 2 ways, one is displaying as it is another is displaying subset of the records based on some filter (through same/another endpoint).

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved using Spring features or without ?

Comment: Depends on how you create this subset. Did you look into Springs `@Cacheable` annotation. If your amount of data is not too large you can just use a simple in memory cache and cache a database records by id.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pageable. Sample controller code for pageable

```
@PostMapping 
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Page<AllInventoryTransactions> fetchAllInwardInventory(@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10, sort = "created", direction = Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable) throws Exception
    {
        return allInventoryService.fetchAllInventory(pageable);
    }
```

You can pass this pageable received from UI directly to Repo. Below is the service method

```
public Page<AllInventoryTransactions> fetchAllInventory(FilterDataList filterDataList, Pageable pageable) throws ParseException 
    {
        Page<AllInventoryTransactions> data = allInventoryRepo.findAll(spec,pageable);
            allInventoryReturnData.setTransactions(data);
        return data;
    }
```

in UI, you can handle logic to make next API call as user scrolls the page

Comment: In real scenario for scroll, it's better to fetch future scroll data before and hide them.  And show just when scroll. Means first call 10 then again 10 but hidden,  scroll show hidden 10 and call for next 10 this way. Good to see you to contribute :)

Comment: @Eklavya. Agree. UI should have that logic implemented for free transition between pages. Also, thank you. Learnt a lot from SO. Now trying to give back.

Comment: @SridharPatnaik How many database calls will be made for getting 10000 records with page size of 10? I was thinking may be there would be a way of fetching all the data with minimum database calls  and cache it on the server side and respond with data to UI on API call but while also keeping pagination in mind. Would this be possible?

Comment: I can think of a solution, but I am not sure if this is most efficient way to do this. You can fetch all required records from DB and cache them as list using @cacheable. This should happen only for first time (you can bind this to some event that happens after logging in).  Then, in your API service method, you can fetch a smaller piece from this huge list through pagination (you can google how to convert list to page). Disclaimer - I am not sure if this will really work. you have to trial and error to see if this really helps.

Comment: @SridharPatnaik, I had the same thought, wasn't sure if its the efficient way, or if there is any better way to get this done. Couldn't find anyone using this approach or any code snippets for this.